# Apache Solr query calculate median of price

Tags: java, apache, solr, solr4

I am using Apache Solr for implementing searching functionality in my application. I have one column which defines the price of services offered by application in respect of different vendors. For Example: there is a service XYZ. And there are many providers that provide XYZ service with different prices.

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    Service Name          Provider Name        City        price
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    XYZ                   A                     ABC         $10
    XYZ                   B                     ABC         $12
    XYZ                   C                     DEF         $14
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I need to calculate the median of prices by filtering records on the basis of the city. Suppose a user search for XYZ service in ABC city. It must return first two rows with a median of $10 and $12. I have searched on google for median function in Solr. But did not get any fruitful.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your index is not distributed, the Solr Stats component can do this. Just request percentile 50: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not provide a ready function. But you can try writting a custom function query for the same.

Below is the link which may help you to achieve the same.

http://www.solrtutorial.com/custom-solr-functionquery.html